# Frame image is not changing while creating installer in windows swt application

Tags: java, swing, install4j

I am creating an windows desktop swt application.

I need to change the frame icon, for that I used

```
frame.setIconImage((new ImageIcon("C:\\Documents and Settings\\arjuns\\Desktop\\logo1 copy.png")).getImage());
```

The icon is displaying when I manually run the code from eclipse, but when I create an installer using Install4j the icon is not appearing.

Can anyone please help me.

[image]

Comment: copy image  in current directory and set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
URL url = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("ressources/logo.png");
Toolkit kit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
Image img = kit.createImage(url);
setIconImage(img);
```

This is similar to the previous answer, but I need to add a bit of information.

You can still use a direct path to your image (C:/User/logo.png) **BUT** imagine you give your program to someone else, he wont have the image in that specific path.

So I recemmend you insert it in your project like so:

[image]

(I usualy do a sperate package for any ressources).

so it will become *ressources/logo.png* and it will work for anybody opening your project.

Answer (score 0):

```
 import java.awt.*;
 import javax.swing.*;
  class set extends  JFrame
 {
set()
{
    setSize(100,100);
    setVisible(true);
    setIconImage(new ImageIcon("navbit-home.png").getImage());
}

public static void main (String[] args) {
new set();
}
}
```

[image]

please set appropriate path.like C:/Documents and Settings/arjuns/Desktop/logo1copy.png

Comment: I had set an appropriate path. The image is displaying when I run the code directly from eclipse. but it is not displaying while creating an installer. Is there any way to set the image with in the package.? instead of giving Desktop path.?

Answer (score 0):

The image should be available in the JAR file you create. Then use `getResource()` to get the image from the jar file.
For example,

```
URL resource = this.getClass().getResource("resources/logo.png");
frame.setIconImage(new ImageIcon(resource).getImage());
```

Here the logo.png is located under 'resources' folder of the class file where this code is executed.